# Large gap in typesetting before group of displayed equations

Tags: spacing

I'm new to LaTeX; my lab professor said it would be great to have our first lab typed up nicely. I plan on doing research in my future, so I figured learning LaTeX early would be an excellent endeavor.

So I just have a huge gap in my typesetting, and I can't see for the life of me why this is happening.

[image: Here, you can see the large gap.]

Relevant code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\degree{^{\circ}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Introduction}

    Furthermore, $KE=\frac{mv^2}{2}=e\Delta V$, which can be used to eliminate the velocity. 
    Moreover, the angle between the trajectory of the emission filament and the magnetic field is $90\degree$ making $\sin(90\degree)=1$. The Lorentz force equation can be simplified and combined with these to derive \textit{Eq. 2}:
    \begin{gather*}
    \abs{\vec{F}} = q\abs{\vec{v}}\abs{\vec{B}}\sin(\theta)\\
    m\frac{v^2}{r}=qvB\\
    \frac{2qV}{r}=qvB\\
    \frac{V}{r}=B\sqrt{\dfrac{q}{2m}}\sqrt{V}
    \end{gather*}
    \begin{equation}
    \boxed{\frac{V}{r}=\lambda\sqrt{V},\lambda\equiv B\sqrt{\frac{q}{2m}}}
    \end{equation}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

BONUS:
I'd love for a larger space between the comma and the lambda.

Any assistance or information would be largely appreciated. I welcome documentation.

Comment: Add `\quad` between comma and `\lambda`

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am about to suggest to use the `twocolumn`option to the article class instead of `multicols` package in this case. Anyway, your examples misses `\usepackage{multicol}`

Comment: Regarding the "huge gap" in the typesetting: Are you referring to the space between the line ending in "rive Eq. (2)" and the subsequent displayed equations, or to the gap at the bottom of the preceding column, i.e., after the line that ends with "and combined with these to de-"?

Comment: I'm referring to the the gap at the bottom of the preceding column. It's quite ugly.

Comment: the `gather*` equation environment does not fit on the previous page, since is not much space left on the bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the multi-line displayed equation environments of the `amsmath` package do not allow column and page breaks. To override this setting, you need to issue the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

Incidentally, don't hard-code cross-references such as "\textit{Eq. 2}". Instead, add a `\label` instruction to the equation in question and use `\ref` -- or, better still, `\cref` of the [cleveref](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package -- to make LaTeX generate the cross-referencing call-out for you.

Finally, as @ChristianHupfer has already noted, you could insert `\quad` to obtain a bit more space after the comma that separates the two main terms in equation 2.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads 'amsmath' automatically
\allowdisplaybreaks     % allow column and page breaks
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\degree{^{\circ}}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref} % for '\cref' macro
\usepackage{multicol}
\setcounter{equation}{1} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Furthermore, $KE=\frac{mv^2}{2}=e\Delta V$, which can be used to eliminate the velocity. 
Moreover, the angle between the trajectory of the emission filament and the magnetic field is $90\degree$, making $\sin(90\degree)=1$. The Lorentz force equation can be simplified and combined with these to derive \cref{eq:2}:
\begin{gather*}
\abs{\vec{F}} = q\abs{\vec{v}}\abs{\vec{B}}\sin(\theta)\\
m\frac{v^2}{r}=qvB\\
\frac{2qV}{r}=qvB\\
\frac{V}{r}=B\sqrt{\dfrac{q}{2m}}\,\sqrt{V}
\end{gather*}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:2}
\boxed{\frac{V}{r}=\lambda\sqrt{V}, 
\quad 
\lambda\equiv B\sqrt{\frac{q}{2m}}}
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! As for \cref, I get an error that states the reference was undefined, even though I added a label to both Eq. 1 and Eq. 2 in the manner you did.

Comment: @Jeesubmyunu - Please state the precise arguments of your `\label` and `\cref` statements. Did you recompile the document twice after adding these statements? Remember also that LaTeX is case-sensitive. Thus, in case you wrote `\label{Eq:1}` and `\cref{eq:1}`, LaTeX will generate a warning (not an error, right?) about "Eq:1" not being defined.

Comment: I used \label{eq:2} after \begin{equation}, and then called it using \cref{eq:2}.

"??" is where the "Eq. 2" reference should be.

Comment: @Jeesubmyunu  - Did you (re)compile *twice*, to let LaTeX resolve all cross-references?

Comment: If Command-T in TeXShop (i.e. "Typeset") is the same as compiling; then yes. I also restarted the program to see if this would work. Apart from \setcounter, my code resembles yours verbatim.

Comment: @Jeesubmyunu - I don't know what else to recommend, except maybe that you post a *new* question in which you describe the problems, with compilable code, that arise in connection with `\label` and `\cref`.